# How to get filtered data from entities in coredata

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a scenario where I know what I need to do but do not know how to implement it in Swift...

I have 2 tables in CoreData and I fetch their values as below

What I need - all friends that are in a particular user friends array

//-----Full Code
Manual CachedUser Class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension CachedUser {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CachedUser> {
    return NSFetchRequest<CachedUser>(entityName: "CachedUser")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var id: String?
@NSManaged public var company: String?
@NSManaged public var isActive: Bool
@NSManaged public var age: Int16
@NSManaged public var email: String?
@NSManaged public var address: String?
@NSManaged public var about: String?
@NSManaged public var registered: String?
@NSManaged public var tags: String?
@NSManaged public var friends: NSSet?

public var wrappedName: String {
    name ?? "Name N/A"
}

public var wrappedId: String {
    id ?? "id N/A"
}

public var wrappedCompany: String {
    company ?? "comapny N/A"
}

public var wrappedIsActive: Bool {
    isActive
}


public var checkIsActive: String {
    return isActive ? "YES" :"NO"
}

public var wrappedEmail: String {
    email ?? "email N/A"
}

public var wrappedAge: Int16 {
    age
}

public var wrappedRegistered: String {
    registered ?? "N/A"
}



public var cachedFriend: [CachedFriend] {
    let set = friends as? Set<CachedFriend> ?? []
    return set.sorted {
        $0.wrappedName < $1.wrappedName
    }
}
```

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for friends
extension CachedUser {

```
@objc(addFriendsObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToFriends(_ value: CachedFriend)

@objc(removeFriendsObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromFriends(_ value: CachedFriend)

@objc(addFriends:)
@NSManaged public func addToFriends(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeFriends:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromFriends(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension CachedUser : Identifiable {

}
```

//-----

//----- CachedUSer

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension CachedFriend {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CachedFriend> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CachedFriend>(entityName: "CachedFriend")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: String?
    @NSManaged public var users: CachedUser?
    
    
    public var wrappedId: String {
        id ?? "Unknown Id"
    }
    
    public var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? "Unknown Name"
    }
    

}

extension CachedFriend : Identifiable {

}
```

//------

//---SwiftUI View where I want the data , Section friends does not show any friends

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    let users: [CachedUser]
    let user: CachedUser
    @State var friendsArray: [CachedFriend] = []
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var friendsData: FetchedResults<CachedFriend>
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            List {
                Section("Name") {
                    Text(user.wrappedName)
                        .font(.body)
                }
                Section("email") {
                    Text(user.wrappedEmail)
                }
                Section("Registration Date") {
                    Text(user.wrappedRegistered)
                }
                Section("Company") {
                    Text(user.wrappedCompany)
                }
                Section("Is Active") {
                    Image(systemName: user.isActive ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "xmark.octagon.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(user.isActive ? Color.green : Color.red)
                }
                
                Section("Friends") {
                    List {
                  
                        ForEach(friendsArray, id:\.self) {friend in
                        Text(friend.wrappedName)
                    }
                        
                    }
                  
                    
                }
                
               
                               
                
            }
            .onAppear {
                friendsArray = Array(user.cachedFriend)
            }
           
           
            
           
            }
           
          
        }
        
   
    
  
}
```

//-----End
Here I have a CachedUser Entity and CachedFriend Entity Image of Relationship attached .

[image]

Every user has an array of friends that I get from json file , that friend array contains name and id....

I know I have to loop over the friends table and filter all names that have the same name as in User Friends array, but I just cannot seem to do it, I have tried below , but they just do not work , can any one point me in right direction. Thanks

```
  @State var friendsArray: [CachedFriend] = []
 let user: CachedUser
func findFriend()  {
    for allFriend in friendsData {
           
        friendsArray = user.cachedFriend.filter({ item in
            item.wrappedId == allFriend.wrappedId
        })
           
    }
    
    print(friendsArray.count)
}
```

Sample of json

```
[
    {
        "id": "50a48fa3-2c0f-4397-ac50-64da464f9954",
        "isActive": false,
        "name": "Alford Rodriguez",
        "age": 21,
        "company": "Imkan",
        "email": "alfordrodriguez@imkan.com",
        "address": "907 Nelson Street, Cotopaxi, South Dakota, 5913",
        "about": "Occaecat consequat elit aliquip magna laboris dolore laboris sunt officia adipisicing reprehenderit sunt. Do in proident consectetur labore. Laboris pariatur quis incididunt nostrud labore ad cillum veniam ipsum ullamco. Dolore laborum commodo veniam nisi. Eu ullamco cillum ex nostrud fugiat eu consequat enim cupidatat. Non incididunt fugiat cupidatat reprehenderit nostrud eiusmod eu sit minim do amet qui cupidatat. Elit aliquip nisi ea veniam proident dolore exercitation irure est deserunt.",
        "registered": "2015-11-10T01:47:18-00:00",
        "tags": [
            "cillum",
            "consequat",
            "deserunt",
            "nostrud",
            "eiusmod",
            "minim",
            "tempor"
        ],
        "friends": [
            {
                "id": "91b5be3d-9a19-4ac2-b2ce-89cc41884ed0",
                "name": "Hawkins Patel"
            },
            {
                "id": "0c395a95-57e2-4d53-b4f6-9b9e46a32cf6",
                "name": "Jewel Sexton"
            },
            {
                "id": "be5918a3-8dc2-4f77-947c-7d02f69a58fe",
                "name": "Berger Robertson"
            },
            {
                "id": "f2f86852-8f2d-46d3-9de5-5bed1af9e4d6",
                "name": "Hess Ford"
            },
            {
                "id": "6ba32d1b-38d7-4b0f-ba33-1275345eacc0",
                "name": "Bonita White"
            },
            {
                "id": "4b9bf1e5-abec-4ee3-8135-3a838df90cef",
                "name": "Sheryl Robinson"
            },
            {
                "id": "5890bacd-f49c-4ea2-b8fa-02db0e083238",
                "name": "Karin Collins"
            },
            {
                "id": "29e0f9ee-71f2-4043-ad36-9d2d6789b2c8",
                "name": "Pace English"
            },
            {
                "id": "aa1f8001-59a3-4b3c-bf5e-4a7e1d8563f2",
                "name": "Pauline Dawson"
            },
            {
                "id": "d09ffb09-8adc-48e1-a532-b99ae72473d4",
                "name": "Russo Carlson"
            },
            {
                "id": "7ef1899e-96e4-4a76-8047-0e49f35d2b2c",
                "name": "Josefina Rivas"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything, the friends of a user is the attribute `user.friends`. This is a Set so you might want to do `friendsArray = Array(user.friends)`

Comment: thanks, I tried - public var cachedFriend: [CachedFriend] {
     
        let set = friends as? Set<CachedFriend> ?? []
        return set.sorted { $0.name! <  $1.name!
        }
    }
Then  ForEach(Array(user.cachedFriend), id:\.self) {friend in
                        Text(friend.wrappedName)
                    }
no error but no out put as well

Comment: This would be easier to debug with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Put together a simple Core Data model with the minimum attributes you need for sorting.

Comment: It’s very hard to read code posted in a comment but that seems to be very far from what I suggested

Comment: his, I am updating the code , I have it at the top , need a few minutes

Comment: hi joakim I have added the manual classes for core data and the SwiftUI view, is there more code I need to post, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `filter` on a CoreData FetchRequest ever.

It is best to do the filtering by `NSPredicate`

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

But in this case all the user's friends are in a variable. If you have the individual `user` all you need to do is something like this...

```
user.friends.allObjects
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with comments showing your name at very top , as I use a way to convert friends as? Set<CachedFriend> , then when I try to display, in SwiftUI View, there is no error but no output as well, kindly guide

Comment: @multiverse use allObjects that will give you the array

Comment: I am trying - using .onAppear {
                friendsArray = Array(user.friends?.allObjects)
            } gives - Argument type '[Any]?' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type error, I have converted it to Array in manual class of core data as let set = friends as? Set<CachedFriend> ?? [] , but its giving no results, thanks

Comment: Why are you putting it into a different variable. That isn't needed. I made the line of code a little more specific. If there are no results/ get an empty array that means that you have not attached any friends to the user. Look for relationships if the guide I attached on the answer